# How do I update dataframe column values with Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

So say I have a bunch of data that goes like this:

```
10-12-2014 3.45
10-12-2014 3.67
10-12-2014 4.0
10-12-2014 5.0
10-13-2014 6.0
10-13-2014 8.9
```

and so on.

I want to put this stuff into a Pandas dataframe in this sort of format:

```
10-12-2014    3.45    3.57    4.0    5.0
10-13-2014    6.0     8.9     etc   etc
```

In order to do that, currently I just have something like this:

```
rows = cursor.fetchall()
df = pd.DataFrame(columns('Date', Val1', 'Val2', 'Val3', 'Val4'))
previous_date = 0
for row in rows:
    if previous_date == 0:
        df.
```

And that's where I'm stuck - I can't seem to find a method that just adds a date and one of the values to the column. I'm also not sure how to update old columns in future iterations, because I've really only been able to find examples of people just adding entire rows. Or is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working from the string to get into that format you can do the following.

1) Get data as df

```
d = """10-12-2014 3.45
10-12-2014 3.67
10-12-2014 4.0
10-12-2014 5.0
10-13-2014 6.0
10-13-2014 8.9"""

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO.StringIO(d),sep="\s",names=['Date','v'])
```

2) group it up and apply a function to index your values.

```
groups = df.groupby('Date')
df =     groups.apply(lambda x: x['v'].reset_index(drop=True))

#line below is equivalent to above but clunkier use if you really want the ValX as columns
#df =     groups.apply(lambda x: pd.Series({"Val{0}".format(1+i):each for i,each in enumerate(x['v'])}))
```

3) reset indexes: use unstack to pivot your value indexes into columns and reset index to reset your date as a column...

```
df =     df.unstack(level=1)
df =     df.reset_index()
```

**edit for speed** if you don't really care about naming the columns

```
groups = df.groupby('Date').indices
df = pd.DataFrame(data= groups.values(),index=groups.keys()).reset_index()
```

**output**

```
         Date  Val1  Val2  Val3  Val4
0  10-12-2014  3.45  3.67     4     5
1  10-13-2014  6.00  8.90   NaN   NaN
```